# gwt text column code not running

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I'm building a Datagrid that contains recipe data contained in a "Recipes" object.  Using TextColumns to fill out the table, but the code where I'm actually creating the columns doesn't seem to run:

```
Window.alert("recipes: " + recipeList.get(0).getIngredients());

TextColumn<Recipes> ingredientColumn = new TextColumn<Recipes>() 
{   
    @Override
    public String getValue(Recipes ingredient) {
        return ingredient.getIngredient();
    }
};
Window.alert("after column creation");
ingredientColumn.setDataStoreName("Ingredients");
colList.add(ingredientColumn);

for (TextColumn col : colList) {
   this.table.addColumn(col, "header");
}
```

The alerts before and after the TextColumn block run (as does any subsequent code), and the data is there and is accurate.  The Datagrid itself was instantiated with the Recipes object, so there isn't any inconsistency there.

Also, I use the dataStoreName to set the column header, and the header actually does appear when I run my code, so the table itself seems to exist, just without the columns.  I've tried putting an alert inside the TextColumn block and that never appeared, so the entire block seems to be getting bypassed.

I'm not sure if/how much more info might be needed to better assist potential answers as I'm quite new to GWT, but should edits be required, I'll be glad to provide whatever info I can to get an accurate answer to my dilemma.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the `myGrid.addColumn(ingredientColumn, "Ingredient")` call?

Comment: It's there - at the end of the method where the table is created, I apply the column names and add the columns/headers.  Sorry forgot to copy that over.  Editing now

Comment: "the header actually does appear when I run my code" - so what's actually missing:  the names of columns in the header, or rows of your data?

Comment: No data appears, only the header.  I know the data is there, and an alert I placed _inside_ the TextColumn block never appeared, as if that part of the code was being entirely bypassed

Comment: `getValue()` is called when grid is being (re)populated with data. Do you have calls to set the data - `table.setRowCount()`, and `table.setRowData()`? Finally, is the height of your grid set to something sufficiently big for rows to be visible?

Comment: I'd failed to call setRowData on the table.  That worked! Thanks so much!! If you want the rep I'd be happy to accept your answer if you repost as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few key things to ensure when setting up a [DataGrid](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html):

- columns are setup and added via `addColumn` calls
- data is applied to the grid either by calling `setRowCount()`/`setRowData()` or via a [data provider](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#data-provider)
- the grid has sufficient height to display at least some rows